# Forcing Jira to pass workflow transition excluding validators and conditions

Tags: java, workflow, jira, jira-plugin

I have a problem with Jira transition that I have to pass. I have service that automatically close issues in Jira (from status Resolved to Close).

It works well but if any condition or validator (or script condition) appears on transition it cannot pass through. **Is there any method to pass transition excluding validators and conditions?** 
Below is my actual code:

```
// issue service
IssueService issueService = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService();

//get user for passing transition           
user  = userUtil.getUserByKey(closeUserKey).getDirectoryUser();

//get issue object
Issue issueObj = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(issueId);

// Parameters for issue
IssueInputParameters issueInputParams = new IssueInputParametersImpl();

//setting comment
issueInputParams.setComment("Issue closed by automatical service after specified time");

//avoid checking fields on screen and additional flag for default values
issueInputParams.setApplyDefaultValuesWhenParameterNotProvided(true);
issueInputParams.setSkipScreenCheck(true);

//validate if transition is ok
TransitionValidationResult validationResult = issueService.validateTransition(user, issueObj.getId(), closeStepId, issueInputParams);

//if is valid pass it               
if (validationResult.isValid()) {
    issueService.transition(user, validationResult);
    IssueService.IssueResult issueResult = issueService.transition(user, validationResult);

} else {
    System.out.println(validationResult.getErrorCollection().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Automation plugin has ability to skip transition condition checks. Its source is open, this is how it does:

```
import static com.atlassian.jira.workflow.TransitionOptions.Builder;
// ....
if (skipConditions)
{
    final TransitionOptions trasitionOptions = new Builder().skipPermissions().skipValidators().setAutomaticTransition().skipConditions().build();
    transitionValidationResult = issueService.validateTransition(user,
            mutableIssue.getId(), getTransitionId(actionId), params, trasitionOptions);
}
```